# Use source twice with akka-stream

Tags: playframework, streaming, akka-stream

I'm using the Play framework for a web application I built. Play 2.5 uses the Akka Stream API to allow streaming of request/response.

I have an endpoint where an incoming file is streamed directly to Google Drive.

I define a `BodyParser` that looks like that:

```
BodyParser("toDrive") { request =>
  Accumulator.source[ByteString].mapFuture { source =>
    Future.successful(Right("Done"))
  }
}
```

I use the source (`Source[ByteString, _]`) and feed it into a `StreamedBody` that I use with the `WSClient` provided by Play.

I would like to use the given `Source` and use for two different HTTP call with the `WSClient`.

I tried the naive approach by passing the same `Source` into two different `WSClient` call, but it failed. I think the solution to my problem is broadcasting.

I want to take what's coming out of the source to create 2 sources to be used by my `WSClient`.

I'm still playing with `Source`, `Flow` and `Sink`. I'm trying to make sense of it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated solution:

```
  Accumulator[ByteString, Either[Result, String]] {
    val s1 = Sink
      .asPublisher[ByteString](fanout = false)
      .mapMaterializedValue(Source.fromPublisher)
      .mapMaterializedValue { source =>
        //do what you need with source
        Future.successful(Right("result 1"))
      }
    val s2 = Sink
      .asPublisher[ByteString](fanout = false)
      .mapMaterializedValue(Source.fromPublisher)
      .mapMaterializedValue { source =>
        //do what you need with source
        Future.successful(Right("result 2"))
      }

    def combine(val1: Future[Either[Result, String]],
                val2: Future[Either[Result, String]]): Future[Either[Result, String]] = {
      for {
        res1 <- val1
        res2 <- val2
      } yield {
        // do something with your result
        res1.right.flatMap(val1 => res2.right.map(val2 => val1 + val2))
      }
    }

    Sink.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(s1, s2)(combine) { implicit b => (sink, sink2) =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[ByteString](2))

      broadcast ~> sink
      broadcast ~> sink2

      SinkShape(broadcast.in)
    })
  }
```

To give a little explanation (AFAIK). I create 2 sink and combine them behind a single one. The `Accumulator.apply` needs 1 `Sink[E, Future[A]]`. The `BodyParser` forces me to use `ByteString` as `E` which is the the `type` of data that goes **in** the sink.

So 2 sinks that takes `ByteString` in and materialize as a `Future[String]`. I convert the `Sink` as a `Source` because the API I use (WsClient) can take a `Source` as a body. This API gives me a `Future[HttpResponse]` (for the sake of the solution, I've simplified this to a `Future[String]` but you could do whatever you want in there.

Now this is where the `akka-streams` API comes into play. I strongly suggest that you look at the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/) to get a better understanding. With that said, here, I used the GraphDSL API to combine my 2 sink behind a single one. Any `ByteString` that comes into the exposed sink is sent into the 2 inner sinks.

*Note: there is a convenient `Sink.combine` function that takes `n` streams and combine them behind one. But using this function means [loosing the materialized value](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#stream-materialization) (in this case, `Future[String]`)*

**The original solution proposed below is not working properly. It is only sending data to one of the source.**

The Play `Accumulator` can also be created by giving it a `Sink`.

I used this approach and this seems to be working so far:

```
BodyParser("toDrive") { request =>
  def sourceToFut(src: Source): Future[T] = ???

  Accumulator[ByteString, Either[Result, T]] {
    Sink
      .asPublisher[ByteString](fanout = true)
      .mapMaterializedValue(Source.fromPublisher)
      .mapMaterializedValue { source =>
        val upload1Fut = sourceToFut(source)
        val upload2Fut = sourceToFut(source)
        for {
          file1 <- upload1Fut
          file2 <- upload2Fut
        } yield {
          (file1, file2)
        }
      }
  }
}
```

The only effective changes this has compared to my initial approach is that I create the `Sink` myself and allow `fanout` so I can use the source twice in two different `WSClient` call.

What do you think @expert?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `.alsoTo()` method of `Source` is what you looking for. Internally it's just broadcast.