# akka stream check source and upload

Tags: akka-stream

I am using akka http `fileUpload` method that produces a `Source[akka.util.ByteString, Any]`.
I would like to handle this source in 2 different threads such as:

```
          ----> Future(check first rows if ok) -> insert object in db -> HTTP response 201 / 400
          |
source ---|
          |
          ----> Future(upload file to S3) -> set object to ready / delete if error...
```

So far, I managed to do something like this:

```
    val f = for {
      uploadResult <- Future(sendFileToS3(filePath, source)) // uploads the file
      (extractedLines, fileSize) <- Future(readFileFromS3(filePath)) // reads the uploaded file
    } yield(uploadResult, extractedLines, fileSize)

    oncomplete(f) {
      case Success((uploadResult, extractedLines, fileSize)) => HTTP OK with id of the object created
      case Success((uploadResult, extractedLines, fileSize)) if ... => HTTP KO
      case Failure(ex) => HTTP KO
    }
```

The problem here is that on large files, the HTTP response is returned when the upload is finished. But what I would like to have is to handle the `uploadResult` separately from checking the first lines.

Something like

```
val f = for {
   (extractedLines, fileSize) <- Future(readSource(source))
} yield(extractedLines, fileSize)

oncomplete(f) {
  case Success((extractedLines, fileSize)) =>
     Future(sendFileToS3AndHandle(filePath, source)) //send in another thread
     HTTP OK with id of the object created

  case Success((extractedLines, fileSize)) if ... => HTTP KO
  case Failure(ex) => HTTP KO
    }
```

Did someone have a similar issue and managed to handle it like this?

I have read something about [using the source twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894250/use-source-twice-with-akka-stream) but it seems over complicated for my use case (and did not managed to do what I want). Also, I tried to use [akka-stream alsoTo](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/alsoTo.html) but this does not solve the issue about returning the response as soon as the first line check is completed.

Thank you for your help or suggestion.

Comment: Take a look at Broadcast: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Broadcast.html You could divide your stream into 2 and upload in one and check the first lines in the other.

Probably you are going to run into troubles when returning response from akka-http before reading the whole request stream, but then you'll need something like `discardBytes` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I managed to use the `Broadcast` operator and generated 2 `Future`s but then I have an issue with the `Stream` stage being cancelled. Probably because of what you are saying in the second part of your answer.